# Scrape a web site how to get a specific link

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, httprequest

hi guys i m scraping a site and it have 3 movies links in each movie it have 3 links, i have the code to get the 3 links but i want to choose 1 and just print that 1 in this case the openload one, also it print it like the whole iframe thing and i like it to print the clear link like this =  'https://openload.co/embed/cosxf9mWZlg/' 
i m also gona put the print here so u guys have a idea how i is rigth now

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
url= ('http://goldfilmesonline.com/goldstone-legendado-online/','http://goldfilmesonline.com/sob-a-sombra-legendado-online/','http://goldfilmesonline.com/fora-do-rumo-dublado-online/')
b=0

while b < len(url):
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36'}
    a = r = requests.get(url[b], headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(a.text,'html.parser')
    x = soup.findAll({'iframe' : 'src'})
    print x
    b+=1
```

this is the print

```
[<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"></iframe>, <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="https://openload.co/embed/noK42_ITHiU/"></iframe>, <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="http://thevid.net/e/zqlcx3byxh/"></iframe>]
[<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"></iframe>, <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="https://openload.co/embed/oMzqATsLLsw/"></iframe>, <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="http://thevid.net/e/rgt2kyrmzdqdbeocwjmspd6/"></iframe>]
[<iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"></iframe>, <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="https://openload.co/embed/cosxf9mWZlg/"></iframe>, <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="https://openload.co/embed/b85sRhsjJ3Q/"></iframe>, <iframe allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" src="http://thevid.net/e/4mvpjkef43pqyhnmg/"></iframe>]
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand what you are asking you want to only print out the iframes where the src has `openload` in it. If this is the case then all you need to do is loop over `x` and check if `openload` is in the `src` value for that frame. If this is true you would then print that frame out.

```
while b < len(url):
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36'}
    a = r = requests.get(url[b], headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(a.text,'html.parser')
    x = soup.findAll({'iframe' : 'src'})
    #print x
    for eachFrame in x:
        currentSRC = eachFrame['src']
        if "openload" in currentSRC.lower(): #lowercased here just in case.
            #print currentSRC #uncomment this if you want just the src link to print.
            #print eachFrame #uncomment this if you want the whole iFrame to print
    b+=1
```

Comment: thanks man i find some codes to do it but yours yours lokes better

Comment: thanks again man. but there is some erros in your code eachFrame shoud be " i ",  I gues and i dont know why it print thevid and openload link dont know why

Comment: just to make sure it work fine whem it is out of my project but whem i make it a def it wont work and print thevid and openload

Comment: I've fixed the code, sorry. I was originally using `i` as the variable name instead of `eachFrame`. I forgot to update `i['src']` to `eachFrame['src']`. This should be the issue you were talking about.

Answer (score 0):

ok guys i have a answer to myself but it doesn't looks rigth,but work... if sme one know a simple or better way use the same modules please help thanks

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import html
url= ('http://goldfilmesonline.com/goldstone-legendado-online/','http://goldfilmesonline.com/sob-a-sombra-legendado-online/','http://goldfilmesonline.com/fora-do-rumo-dublado-online/')
b=0

while b < len(url):
    headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36'}
    a = r = requests.get(url[b], headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(a.text,'html.parser')
    x = soup.findAll({'iframe' : 'src'})
    c = x[1]
    a = re.compile('src="(.+?)"').findall(str(c))
    print a
    b+=1
```

Comment: You shouldn't ask new questions  in your answers

Comment: See my answer below, if that doesn't answer your question comment on it and let me know.

Comment: Thanks Michael it did and it help a lot I get to the the same thing with a different code but I decided to use your thanks a lot